# Basic Matlab FOR function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to execute this matlab chart. Here is my code so far which does not seem to work.

Basically, if X is greater then 10, then it goes to a section where X = X - index, and index is equal to the start value. Each time the loop is executed, the the value of X is added to the value of the index, and the X and the index are ran back through the X = X + index section, until the index is above the end value.

If X<=10, then it goes to X = X + index, and index is equal to the start value. Each time the loop is executed, the index is added to the X to update the X,the index is added to the increment to update the index , and the X and the index are ran back through the X = X + index section, until the index is above the end value.

Does this make sense?

```
if (X > 10);
   index = start_value;
   for X = [X:index + increment :end_value];
      Y= X - index;
      index = index + increment;
      fprintf('%i, %i\n', Y, index)
   end
elseif (X <= 10)
   index = start_value;
   for X = [X: index + increment :end_value];
      Y = X + index;
      index = index + increment;
      fprintf('%i, %i\n', Y, index)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but letting `X` loop over something that depends on `X` just makes things less clear (and will probably not work as you expect it to).

Note that the normal syntax of a `for` loop would be:

```
for t = startpoint:increment:endpoint
  % do stuff 
  % You can read here from t, startpoint,increment,endpoint but not update them
end
```

Comment: If you would be required to change the increment or endpoint during the loop you will have to use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your description and code are in total contradiction... please check the two for loops carefully. I will list the discrepancies:

1. if X is greater then 10, then it goes to a section where `X = X - index` : following line of the code does not indicate that:

`for X = [X:index + increment :end_value]; %3rd line of your code`

1. Each time the loop is executed, the index is subtracted from the increment : following line of code does not indicate that:

`index = index + increment; %5th line of your code`

1. the X and the index are ran back through the `X = X + index section`, until the index is above the end value : not clear what you want to say
2. If `X<=10`, then it goes to `X = X + index` : 10th line of the code does not indicate that

Please correct these errors.

Comment: Parag, I updated the description to make more sense. How does that look now?

Comment: @user2105984 can you please tell me where you have made changes. I don't see any change. Please refer to my answer and explain accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to specify I did not write the explanation of what the code was trying to accompolish correctly. I changed the line to say " the the value of X is added to the value of the index, and the X and the index are ran back through the X = X + index section into the loop"

Comment: The above comment is itself not clear to me.
1. `the value of X is added to the value of the index` - I don't see that.
2. `the X and the index are ran back through the X = X + index section into the loop` - What do you mean by this?